# Is there any software for selectively restoring apps from an iOS backup?

Tags: ios, backup

I'm in need of a solution that would allow me to choose individual iOS apps from a full iPhone backup made with iTunes, and to restore only those. Ideally, nothing else than the selected apps would be affected on the phone.

There's no requirement to migrate the apps between different versions of iOS or from one iPhone to another, although such ability certainly wouldn't hurt. I'm using iOS 14 on the device.

The use case is to fix the all too usual grievance where you update an app only to see that it has either evolved in a way you don't like, or that the new version doesn't work well with your device–OS combination. While it would be possible to brace for this by backing up the device before each and every app update, that quickly becomes a hassle, and a full restore isn't preferred because of the time it takes and the fact that it tends to invalidate identities tied to the device from banking or two-factor authentication apps, for example.

Comment: The apps aren't in the backups these days. They used to be up to maybe iOS 9 or so. If you have a backup from several years ago you can pick apps out of it & send them to the phone with Configurator2 [Apple, freeware] but not for anything recent. Even reverting to a full backup wouldn't let you go back 'downhill'. Unless your phone is generationally limited to iOS 14 you couldn't go back to that either, you'd get 15.6.1.

Comment: @Tetsujin – I'm aware that the apps aren't physically in the backup and are re-downloaded from App Store as part of the restore, but I think I've been able to downgrade apps this way (the app list in the backup probably includes version information, and the same version is installed during restore if it's still present in the App Store repository – which seems to vary between different developers, so it doesn't always work). The tool I'm looking for, if one exists, would have to download the desired version from App Store, but for the user, the end result would be the same.